# What's a socially acceptable way to obtain the "Peer Pressure" badge?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, voting, badges

The "[Peer Pressure](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure)" badge has the requirement of "Delete own post with score of -3 or lower".

There has already been a post [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17380/peer-pressure-badge-removal) talking about removing it. However, what if a person actually *wanted* to earn this badge on purpose (we could hypothesize a bunch of reasons why a person would want to do so - being a completionist being one of them)? What is an "okay" way to post a bad answer in such a way that you get enough downvotes on them that is also not so bad that it annoys everyone that reads it?

Comment: If you want to get the badge in earnest, just post a lot of answers that you're confident are of high quality. If you do this enough, maybe one of your well intentioned answers will turn out to be utterly wrong and get to -3 before you can delete it. (Disclaimer: This has not happened to the top 4 reputation earners, but it has happened to the 5th. So, I guess some people are just really good at not writing bad answers. Too bad if that's you, I guess)

Comment: +1 because right now this question is at -3.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Who is the 5th? Which answer was that?

Comment: @Did, I don't know whether robjohn is #5, but he was awarded the badge on 25 May at 8:53. I got one 18 January 2013 at 2:19.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for the information.

Comment: @Did If you are wondering whether you have this badge, you can go to your profile page and look at [badges tab](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=badges). If you find the badge you can click on the badge to see more information. In your case, you get [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure?userid=6179). All I can see there is that you were awarded this badge on Mar 20 '15 at 22:10. I am not sure whether more information is displayed to you.

Comment: If you want to find which post was it, you can try to look at your deleted posts to see whether you will find something which was deleted at that time. As explained [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/13949), you can do see your deleted posts by [searching with the option deleted:1](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=deleted%3a1). Since you are interested in particular date, sorting the results by activity might be useful. (Still, if you have many deleted posts, it might be not easy to find the right one.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Wow, you are impressive... Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Martin: Ordering by score might be proved to be more productive, when looking for posts deleted with score -3 or lower.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey When I wrote: "I am not sure whether more information is displayed to you." I meant on the page showing the badge to the badge owner. About URLs of deleted posts, you are only partially right. Since Did has above 10k reputation points, he can find all *his* deleted posts, as explained [in the answer I linked above](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13948/is-there-any-way-to-see-my-deleted-questions-or-answers/13949#13949). To see deleted posts by other users, you need to have url and [10k+ reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I quickly noticed that [the answer for which I got the badge](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1799210) was wrong and deleted it 56 seconds after posting it. However, in those 56 seconds, it was downvoted 3 times. I was amazed at the ferocity with which it was downvoted.

Comment: After posting my last comment, someone removed their downvote. I didn't know that that was possible on a deleted answer, but apparently it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not that you can earn the 'peer pressure' badge only be deleting a -3 **wrong answer**. You can get the badge by deleting a -3 **wrong question** too.

So just ask a small and very ambiguous stupid enough question, get your 3 downvotes quick enough (the stupider the question, the faster the downvotes). People are very quick to downvote but way hesitant to upvote. So getting downvotes should be a cakewalk. Delete your question as soon as you get -3 so as not to waste anyone's time, and get the badge.

Since you got the downvotes fast enough, you wasted less time of others, and you got your badge too.

Source: I have the badge, although I wasn't seeking it deliberately :-)
If you have enough reputation, you can even see my deleted question I guess.

Comment: I think this answer supports the idea that the badge should be removed!

Comment: I'm more hesitant to downvote than to upvote.  Upvoting should be positive!